# LINQ Query (Group BY) one column

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following classes

```
public class DashboardTile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DashboardTileBO : DashboardTile
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public List<DashboardTileBO> DashboardTiles { get; set; }
}
```

I have list of tiles in which some tiles are child of other.Now I want to show my list of tiles in such a way that if it has childs it gets added to the list.

query I am trying

```
 var allDashBoardTiles = (from a in context.DashboardTiles
                                         group a by a.CategoryID into b 
                                         select new BusinessObjects.DashboardTileBO
                                         {
                                             ID = a.ID,
                                             Name = a.Name,
                                             Description = b.Description,
                                             DashboardTiles = b.ToList(),
                                         }).ToList();

            var list = context.DashboardUserTiles.Where(a => a.UserID == userId).Select(a => a.DashboardTileID).ToList();

            allDashBoardTiles.ForEach(a => a.IsChecked = list.Contains(a.ID));
```

Now in above query when I use group clause and in select if I use a.ID,a.Name etc it says that it doesnot contain definitionor extension method for it.

Table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the properties of `a` directly because `GroupBy` returns `IGrouping<TKey,T>`. You can include other columns also in your group by and access them like this:-

```
 (from a in context.DashboardTiles
 group a by new { a.CategoryID, a.ID, a.Name } into b 
 select new BusinessObjects.DashboardTileBO
        {
            ID = b.Key.ID,
            Name = b.Key.Name,
            DashboardTiles = b.ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Also, I guess the property `DashboardTiles` in `DashboardTileBO` class should be `List<DashboardTile>` instead of `List<DashboardTileBO>`, otherwise we cannot fetch it from DashboardTiles data.

Comment: thanks yes now I am able to access it but now it says cannot convert list of int to list of dashboardtilebo how to get my list of subcategory here

Comment: @rupinder18 - It must be giving the error `Cannot convert from list of dashboardtile to list of dashboardtilebo` and not list of integer. Please check my update I guess your property should consist of `DashboardTile` instead of `DashboardTileBO`